# Can't sign in to Firebase

Tags: firebase

Whenever I try to sign in to Firebase, it gives me this error:

[image]

I tried searching it up everywhere but it yields no results. What am I supposed to do?

Everyone else is able to use it, but I can't. Is there a solution or do I need to buy a Google Workspace subscription?

Comment: If you're having problem signing in to the Firebase console, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.